# linux - windows don't repaint unless stretched

Tags: linux, video

I think a recent change to my kernel configuration is causing my video to be messed up with certain windows (chromium, firefox, libreoffice) or at least those are the ones I've used.  The problem is that I don't have a before and after picture of the kernel configuration, so I'm shooting in the dark as to what exactly did it.  One of the changes I did was to make a large part of the video drivers my systems use as modules instead of built-in.

Is this a common problem / any ideas as to what may have caused this?

Comment: I've seen this recently on fedora 23 using the nvidia driver. Fresh install, so I don't have a before, but never had this problem with Fedora 21 or earlier on the same hardware.

Comment: Are you using KDE by any chance?

Comment: Oddly enough, it appears the problem resolved itself after updating my system.  I'm speculating that certain versions of the linux kernel were affected and the most recent ones are fixed, 4.4.3+.  I'm using intel, XFCE, on funtoo.

Comment: I switched back to making all of the video drivers modules and that seems to be the cause.  Now, the problem I have is youtube videos don't render in chromium, but if I download them first then play them in parole, they work fine.  I don't see any sort of system errors, but I should run chromium in debug mode to see what's going on.